# Linq to Entities Wildcard %

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to do a linq to entities statement and one of the conditions is going to contain the wild card %

I have the following code which if i remove the % from the 2 combo boxes i get results

```
var SLogged = from p in OEEEntity.Scrappages
                             where p.Date >= StartDate
                             where p.Date <= EndDate
                             where p.LogType.Contains(cmbType.Text)
                             where p.ScrapCode.Contains(cmbCode.Text)
                             orderby p.Date ascending
                             select p;
```

The values that will contain the % are cmbType and cmbCode

anyone know how i can do this.

Comment: Why not just remove the `%` from the string?  Since you use `contains` that should translate to SQL that uses `%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Contains("aaa")` is equivalent to `LIKE '%aaa%'`

`.StartsWith("aaa")` is equivalent to `LIKE 'aaa%'`

`.EndsWith("aaa")` is equivalent to `LIKE '%aaa'`

So you don't have to add '%' manually.

Comment: What im looking is if the user does select % from the dropdown not the filter by the items in the combobox. Almost like skipping out the where.

Comment: You can always manage what the user selects and what your query does.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of dealing with wildcard characters is to use [PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx)

```
var SLogged = (from p in OEEEntity.Scrappages
                             where p.Date >= StartDate
                             && p.Date <= EndDate
                             && SqlFunctions.PatIndex(cmbType.Text, p.LogType) > 0 
                             && SqlFunctions.PatIndex(cmbCode.Text,p.ScrapCode) > 0 
                             orderby p.Date ascending
                             select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering the QUESTION, since the OP didn't actually ask his problem in the OP.

```
var queryText = cmbType.Text;
var SLogged = from p in OEEEntity.Scrappages
                         where p.Date >= StartDate
                         where p.Date <= EndDate
                         where p.LogType.Contains(queryText) 
                                 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText)
                         where p.ScrapCode.Contains(queryText) 
                                 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText)
                         orderby p.Date ascending
                         select p;
```